# Typescript flexible types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can I enforce a value to exist within a list in typescript specifically w/ enums. Is this accomplishable w/ typescript type definitions?

```
enum Friend {
  JOHN,
  SALLY,
  PAUL,
}

type MyFriends = {
   friends: Friend[],
   bestFriend: <> //How can I enforce that this value exists within the supplied list of friends?
}
```

Comment: That would really be a *value* check, not a *type* check.

Comment: Enforce where?  If `type MyFriends = { friends: Friend[], bestFriend: Friend }` doesn't meet your needs could you show how?

Comment: I don't think this is feasible. There's a lot of questions regarding what behavior you'd expect. For example, what if I set friends to be the empty list? That should not be able to exist according to your constraint. Or, more generally, which friend should be picked if the current bestFriend gets removed from the list?

Answer (score 3):

```
enum Friend {
  JOHN,
  SALLY,
  PAUL,
}

// solution at type level
// type constructor
type MyFriends<F extends Friend[]> = {
   friends: F,
   bestFriend: F[number]
}

// make specific instance of it:
type JohnFriends = MyFriends<[Friend.SALLY,Friend.PAUL]>
const johnFriends: JohnFriends = {
    friends: [Friend.SALLY,Friend.PAUL],
    bestFriend: Friend.SALLY // can be only a member of friends array
}
const errorJohnFriends: JohnFriends = {
    friends: [Friend.SALLY,Friend.PAUL],
    bestFriend: Friend.JOHN // error as it should!
}

// solution at value level with value constructor
// additionaly we can make value constructor for proper creating such type of value
const makeFriends = <A extends Friend[], BF extends A[number]>(friends: A, bestFriend: BF): MyFriends<A> => ({
    friends,
    bestFriend
})

// propelry created value of MyFriends
const johnFriends2 = makeFriends([Friend.PAUL, Friend.JOHN], Friend.JOHN); 
const errorJohnFriends2 = makeFriends([Friend.PAUL, Friend.JOHN], Friend.SALLY); // error as it should
```

What we did here is:

- `MyFriends` generic type which has argument of `Friend`, it means we pass which exactly elements from `Friends` enum will be available in `friends` property
- `bestFriend: F[number]` - we say second field can be only value which exists in the `friends` array, thanks to that we cannot use Enum member which is not provided in the first one

Comment: oh, *now* I understand what the question is asking for.